# .Net Excel Add In Help

Tags: c#, .net, excel, add-in

I am interested in creating a couple of add-ins for Office 2003 & 2007 for work and home.  I see the project templates in VS2008 for creating the addins but I am un-clear as to what to do next.  I also have had great difficulty finding direction online so far. I am not looking for cut and paste code but rather a finger pointing in the direction of a *Hello World*, of sorts, for creating addins using VS8's templates.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the time and replies!

Between *gkrodgers* and *Perpetualcoder's* responses I was lead to my ultimate destination --> [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx)

Why I had such a time finding this in the first place is beyond me.

Thanks you two for giving me the finger!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is the article that got me started when I needed to write a Word add-in:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302896

and this is my *actual* "Hello World" code! :-)

```
public void OnStartupComplete(ref System.Array custom)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb496949.aspx) are a bunch of videos that might show you the way.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

recently I into writing a ui app for ms project. Vs2008 does an amazing job of making it very easy. I used c# (not having used it before at all) and what I found works best is a combination of looking at the API of the imported packages and the editor's code completion tool. But I agree, trying to find tutorials and even good Api documentation is not fun...coming from Java world that is.

Answer (score 0):

For office automation, the best tool is the VSTA: visual studio tools for automation.

This will include the SDK/ IDE etc for developing office addins etc.